Is "choose k from n without replacement" a solution to randomly choosing a subset of distinct integers with equal probability?
To sample k integers from range [1, n], with order doesn't matter,  could one conduct a n-choose-k experiment? does it give equal probability for each number to be chosen?
To my understanding, n choose k without replacement is equivalently choosing a single elements from the reservoir k times, which means later selections have slightly different probability dynamics compared to earlier selections. Thus, the elements are not selected equally likely.
Is my understanding correct? or where I am missing?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes it does give equal probability for each number to be chosen.
You might also clarify that (presumably, you intend that) order of selection is regarded as irrelevant.
So, if $~n=4, ~k = 2,~$ then $~\displaystyle \binom{n}{k} = \binom{4}{2} = 6,~$ and the corresponding subsets are $\{1,2\}, ~\{1,3\}, ~\{1,4\}, ~\{2,3\}, ~\{2,4\}, ~\{3,4\}.~$
Note that each of the elements in $~\{1,2,3,4\}~$ appears in exactly $~3~$ of the $~6~$ subsets, which reinforces the idea that each of the elements in $~\{1,2,3,4\},~$ is selected with equal probability.

Many thanks for the answer mate, the scheme to select specific subset indeed gives equal probability, however, I was wondering is it essentially equivalent to the scheme I described, i.e., choose k times from reservoir. If it is, could you teach what defect exists in my statement?

@PkDrew No, your scheme is inconsistent.  For example, with $~n = 4, ~k = 2, ~$ each element appears in $~3~$ of the subsets.  To understand the difficulty with your scheme, you have to understand what it means to enumerate all possible ways of (for example) choosing $~2~$ elements from a set of $~4~$ elements, sampling without replacement, where order of selection is regarded as irrelevant.  The sample in my answer should give you a basic guide.  ...see next comment

@PkDrew In fact, for $~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ and $~k \in {1,2,\cdots,n-1},~$ the enumeration is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k! ~(n-k)!}.$$  See also Pascal's Triangle.

Greatly appreciate the explanations, I'll give them a reading and try to understand the difference, kindly pardon my dullness.
